# MBP 13" Early 2011 Thunderbolt Firmware Version - How to update 22.1 to latest version

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, firmware

I bought a Kanex KTU10 to add USB 3.0 support on my machine because its only on USB 2.0. The product said my machine can support the product but when I plug it in it didn't work, while Mini DP to HDMI can work.

Kanex support told me to update my firmware but I am on MacOS Sierra now how do I update my Thunderbolt Firmware on my OS version? Image below is the information of my Thunderbolt.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on macOS Sierra you should already have the latest firmware version compatible with your MBP.

As far as I know, the only firmware update for your MBP was issued about five years ago. For more info, refer to [About EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518).

Comment: So any suggestions on how to do it on my Mac OS Sierra?

Comment: Well, if there was an update, it really should have just happened via the macOS Sierra installation. TBH, I'd be surprised if there was an update for an early 2011 model - depending on your location, your MBP is either considered vintage or obsolete by Apple. You may want to refer to: [Vintage and obsolete products](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201624).

Comment: @Monomeeth Telling people their computers are vintage or obsolete is not helpful and in fact obnoxious. If you are the kind of person who doesn't give a damn about the environment (like Apple executives) please keep it to yourself. The rest of us would like to keep our computers running for the longest possible usable life.

Comment: @Foliovision I appreciate the feedback, however all I was trying to do was point out that **Apple** considers their MacBook to be vintage or obsolete after a certain period of time and therefore they're not likely to offer updates for those models. I can see how this may be taken as offensive, but it's better in my opinion to let people know what the facts are relating to the level of support still available to them from Apple. As for me personally, I still have old Macs in use dating back to Jan 2002, so please don't assume that because I pointed out Apple's policy that I agree with it.